# Strange files shows up in my /home when Ubuntu starts

Tags: ubuntu, file-management, jre, phpstorm

Recently, I've noticed some strange files showing up in my /home directory every time when I turn on/restart my computer.

They just appears and the names means nothing, I can delet them as normal files (no permissions issues), but in the next day, there they are. Below is a recent screenshot of these files.

[image: screen]

As I said, the names doesn't follow any convention, the content is unreadable or just empty and the file size varies from 0 to 1 byte, so far as can check.

This is not affecting my use or daily experience, but is annoying. Anyone has a clue of what cause it?

**UPDATE**

After a lot of tests running programs and restarting the computer for each software I have installed, I'm almost sure that these files are related with my PHPStorm installation. 
Every time when I use it, I have the files when restart. Could it be related with Java? Updating tgas of question to reflect this new info.

INFO

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHPStorm 2017.1
- openjdk version "1.8.0_131"

Comment: What is the content of those files ? You could try inotify tools but since its at boot this might be difficult.

Comment: Sometimes the files hasn't any content (0 byte), but sometimes the content is just a version of its title, so, not meaningful symbols.